# Как сделать проверку в mysql

Tags: python, mysql, telebot

Python библиотека telebot бд mysql.Как в mysql сделать проверку: Существует ли уже такой users_id,если нет то ВЫПОЛНИТЬ ЗАПРОС,если есть то НЕ ВЫП[image: На скрине столбцы в бд,id который добавляется автоматом и users_id который и нужно проверить]ОЛНЯТЬ запрос.2й день уже сижу,прошу помощи

Comment: Что-то наподобие *if ("SELECT *  FROM table WHERE user_id == user_id"):*, если запрос к бд вернёт данные, то значит есть такой пользователь. Запрос

Comment: Покажите полный запрос пожалуйста,я не понимаю как

Comment: Наверное в начале нужно разобраться тогда с бд или ормкой, а не задавать вопросы и ждать что кто-то за тебя напишет код.

Comment: Существует несколько способов . Выбор способа зависит от того, что за запрос вы хотите выполнить после проверки. Общее правило на SO - чем детальнее описана задача, тем полезнее для вас будут ответы

Comment: После проверки нужно выполнить запрос вставки id в users_id